# Gerrit API - get CommitInfo with optional WEB_LINKS - query syntax

Tags: api, rest, gerrit

I would like to create a REST query for Gerrit that would return `CommitInfo` entity but with a optional field containing so-called `WEB_LINKS`, that is "links to the commit in external sites as a list of `WebLinkInfo` entities."

This is how the query looks for obtaining the 'standard' CommitIinfo request (**works correct**):
`https://<GERRIT_HOST>/a/projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/commits/<COMMIT_SHA>`

According to the documentation (
1. https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#commit-info
2. https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#commit-info
)

I've written this:
`https://<GERRIT_HOST>/a/projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/commits/<COMMIT_SHA>/?o=CURRENT_COMMIT&o=WEB_LINKS` but I am getting *Er=400 Client Error*...

Could you please provide the corrent syntax of the query? In advance, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the WEB_LINKS info, the correct would be to add "?links" at the end of the command but I think this feature isn't available in [project "Get Commit" endpoint](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#get-commit).

But...

I was able to get this information using the [change "Get Commit" endpoint](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-commit) using:

```
https://<GERRIT_HOST>/a/changes/<CHANGE_ID>/revisions/<COMMIT_SHA>/commit?links
```

Like for example:

```
https://<GERRIT_HOST>/a/changes/71135/revisions/c0d5d23ea05bf6e2011b453f1ee8c47a4da60821/commit?links
```

Comment: Is there a flaw in part of the doc then?
Specifically, here:
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#commit-info

Perhaps it may also sth to do with the plug-ins installed on the Host's Gerrit service?
Cheers!

Comment: Where did you find that you can use the "o=WEB_LINKS" option in the Get Commit endpoint to get the web_links information?

Comment: In the very link I posted in the comment above which states that `web_links` are optional field - perhaps I misunderstand it somehow.
@marcelo, are you albe to explain how the query should look in order to obtain URL to the commit knowing its' SHA? I'd much appreciate it! -M

Comment: I think this is not implemented yet, I updated the answer adding a workaround.